# Нужны ли в этих предложениях запятые? 6

Tags: пунктуация

1) Глупо(,) на самом деле.
2) Потому что история(,) очевидно(,) слишком скучный предмет.

Comment: А вы как думаете?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что Д/З

Comment: Почему не соответствует теме?

Comment: Потому, что домашние задания тут не делают. Покажите, что вы хотя бы попытались разобраться самостоятельно - и вам помогут.

Comment: Это даже не Д/З. Я пыталась разобраться самостоятельно, но не сообо уверена в правильности. Поэтому и прошу помощи.

Comment: Так никто вам не мешает показать всем, что пытались. Правило хотя бы напишите.

Comment: На сайте видела много подобных вопросов, но почему-то никто не придирался.

Comment: На каком сайте? У нас это линия постоянная. ДЗ за двоечников не делаются.  И я голосую за закрытие подобных вопросов последовательно и регулярно. ***Подобных***, разуемется.

Answer (score 1):

Только автор этих предложений знает, что именно имеется в виду.

И "в самом деле" и "очевидно" могут быть как вводными, то есть обособляться, и членами предложения, не требующими обособления.

*На самом деле* и *очевидно* - вводные слова, выражающие оценку говорящим степени достоверности сообщаемого (уверенность, предположение, возможность, неуверенность).

Если первое предложение можно прочитать как "Это на самом деле глупо", то есть, с точки зрения автора, нечто действительно глупо, знаки не нужны. Если это же "на самом деле" эмоциональное, вроде "чёрт возьми!", то перед нами вводное.

То же и со вторым предложением. Если "очевидно" по смыслу, вкладываемому автором, указует на бесспорность, явность некоего явления, знаки не нужны. Если есть элемент сомнения, колебания, то перед нами вводное.

См. Словарь-справочник по пунктуации:

[**на самом деле**](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/407/%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5);

[**очевидно**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_519).

Answer (score 1):

**Я бы в обоих случаях обособила вводные слова.** Конечно,   они могут выступать  в роли  обстоятельства и не обособляться, но здесь не тот случай.

**Дело в том. что нужно учитывать структуру предложения.**

1) **Глупо, на самом деле.** Здесь короткая эмоциональная оценка, явная пауза, два ударения. Если не будет обособления, то  логическим ударением должна выделяться только вводная часть при отсутствии паузы: Глупо на сАмом деле. (Если делаем два ударения, то обязательно обозначаем паузу).

Сравнить: Всё это глупо на самом деле (нет обособления).

2) **Потому что история, очевидно, слишком скучный предмет.** Здесь вводное слово произносится с явно вставочной интонацией (две паузы, общее понижение тона).

Попробуем оценить парный вариант: **Потому что история // очевИдно слишком скучный предмет.** Обстоятельство "очевидно" примыкает ко второй части и выделяется логическим ударением. Произнести это сложно, да и семантика утверждения сомнительна.

**Вывод**: нет здесь авторского выбора, в обоих случаях обособление вводных слов.